# How can I remove the repetitive joins from this SELECT query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres database with two tables: `services` and `meta`.

The first table stores the "core" information the application needs, and the app also has a "custom field" feature implemented similar to how Wordpress's `wp_post_meta` table works.

Users can add on meta rows with arbitrary keys and values, in a one-to-many relationship with the service.

The schema of the meta table is:

- id
- key (string)
- value (string)
- service_id (foreign key)

That works great for the app, so I'm not interested in changing the schema, but for some infrequently used admin dashboards I need to get back a list of services with several of the meta rows joined on **as columns**.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    services.*,
    meta1.value AS funding,
    meta2.value AS ownership
FROM services

JOIN meta meta1
    ON services.id = meta.service_id
    AND meta.key = 'Funding'

JOIN meta meta2
    ON services.id = meta2.service_id
    AND meta2.key = 'Ownership'
```

Now, this works great, but I have to do another join every time I want to add another meta value.

That seems like it will slow down the query and make it less readable.

**Is there a good way to refactor this to keep it easy to read and fast to run?**

---

here's an attempted refactor using OR, which doesn't work:

```
SELECT
    *,
    meta.value AS funding,
    meta.value AS ownership
FROM services

JOIN meta
    ON services.id = meta.service_id
    AND meta.key = 'Funding' OR meta.key = 'Ownership'
```

Comment: You just need to use an OR for the additional cases in the existing JOIN, but the query optimizer is hopefully (maybe?) already realizing this.

Comment: how might i do that? i've tried to refactor it using OR but it gets confused about which value belongs in which column

Comment: Aggregating the key/value pairs into a JSON value might be an alternative. Do you absolutely need those as separate columns?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to aggregate the key/value pairs into a JSON value with a derived table:

```
select srv.*, 
       mv.vals ->> 'Funding' as funding,
       mv.vals ->> 'Ownership' as ownership
from services srv
  cross join lateral (
     select jsonb_object_agg(m.key, m.value) as vals
     from meta m
     where m.key in ('Funding', 'Ownership')
       and m.service_id = srv.id
  ) as mv
```

If your application can handle the JSON, then maybe the conversion into two separate columns isn't actually necessary which would avoid the repetition of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT s.*, m.funding, m.ownership
FROM services s JOIN
     (SELECT m.service_id, 
             MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 'Funding') as Funding,
             MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 'Ownership') as Ownership
      FROM meta m
      GROUP BY m.service_id
     ) m
     ON m.service_id = s.id
```